Improve execution time of a query that populates data
Good morning everyone, how are you?
I need help related to a process whose popular purpose is data from one table to another, at the moment I'm using spring boot with native query, but it's taking more than 30 minutes, java method:
    @Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "WITH transformed_source AS ( "
        + "    SELECT "
        + "        lcp.client, "
        + "        lcp.product_id, "
        + "        lcp.store_id, "
        + "        CASE "
        + "            WHEN lcp.\"source\" = :client THEN 'PROPRIA' "
        + "            WHEN lcp.\"source\" = 'INFOPRICE - INFOPANEL' THEN 'INFOPANEL' "
        + "            WHEN lcp.\"source\" = 'INFOPRICE - MPDV' THEN 'MPDV' "
        + "            ELSE lcp.\"source\" "
        + "            END AS source "
        + "    FROM "
        + "        last_competitor_prices lcp "
        + "    WHERE "
        + "            lcp.client = :client "
        + "      AND lcp.\"source\" IS NOT NULL "
        + "      AND lcp.date BETWEEN :startingDate AND :endingDate "
        + "), "
        + "     agg_source AS ( "
        + "         SELECT "
        + "             product_id, "
        + "             store_id, "
        + "             string_agg(DISTINCT \"source\", '-' ORDER BY \"source\") AS \"source\" "
        + "         FROM "
        + "             transformed_source "
        + "         GROUP BY "
        + "             product_id, "
        + "             store_id "
        + "     ), "
        + "     agg_competitor_prices AS ( "
        + "         SELECT "
        + "             lcp.store_id, "
        + "             lcp.product_id, "
        + "             CAST(AVG(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS avg_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             CAST(MIN(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS min_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             CAST(MAX(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS max_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             CAST(AVG(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_family_id, lcp.competitor_store_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS avg_competitor_price_family, "
        + "             CAST(MIN(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_family_id, lcp.competitor_store_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS min_competitor_price_family, "
        + "             CAST(MAX(lcp.price_retail) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.store_id, lcp.product_family_id, lcp.competitor_store_id) AS DECIMAL(17, 2)) AS max_competitor_price_family, "
        + "             MAX(lcp.date) OVER (PARTITION BY lcp.client, lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id) AS max_date_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             ags.\"source\" "
        + "         FROM "
        + "             last_competitor_prices lcp "
        + "                 LEFT JOIN "
        + "             agg_source ags ON lcp.product_id = ags.product_id AND lcp.store_id = ags.store_id "
        + "         WHERE "
        + "                 lcp.client = :client "
        + "           AND lcp.date BETWEEN :startingDate AND :endingDate "
        + "     ), "
        + "     final_competitor_prices AS ( "
        + "         SELECT "
        + "             store_id, "
        + "             product_id, "
        + "             avg_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             min_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             max_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             max_date_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             source, "
        + "             AVG(avg_competitor_price_family) AS avg_competitor_price_family, "
        + "             AVG(min_competitor_price_family) AS min_competitor_price_family, "
        + "             AVG(max_competitor_price_family) AS max_competitor_price_family "
        + "         FROM "
        + "             agg_competitor_prices "
        + "         GROUP BY "
        + "             store_id, "
        + "             product_id, "
        + "             avg_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             min_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             max_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             max_date_competitor_price_product, "
        + "             source "
        + "     ) "
        + "UPDATE "
        + "    products_to_be_priced ptb "
        + "SET "
        + "    acp_avg_competitor_price_product = fcp.avg_competitor_price_product, "
        + "    acp_min_competitor_price_product = fcp.min_competitor_price_product, "
        + "    acp_max_competitor_price_product = fcp.max_competitor_price_product, "
        + "    acp_avg_competitor_price_family = fcp.avg_competitor_price_family, "
        + "    acp_min_competitor_price_family = fcp.min_competitor_price_family, "
        + "    acp_max_competitor_price_family = fcp.max_competitor_price_family, "
        + "    acp_max_date_competitor_price_product = fcp.max_date_competitor_price_product, "
        + "    acp_days_competitor_price = :competitorDays, "
        + "    source = fcp.source "
        + "FROM "
        + "    final_competitor_prices fcp "
        + "WHERE "
        + "        ptb.client = :client "
        + "  AND ptb.product_id = fcp.product_id "
        + "  AND ptb.store_id = fcp.store_id")
void populateProductToBePricedByLastCompetitorPrice(@Param("client") String client, @Param("startingDate") LocalDate startingDate,
                                                    @Param("endingDate") LocalDate endingDate, @Param("competitorDays") int competitorDays);

I have already created some indexes on the last_competitor_prices tables:
create index if not exists idx_lcp_date_client_product_store
on public.last_competitor_prices (date, client, product_id, store_id);

create index if not exists last_competitor_prices_client_store_id_product_id_idx
on public.last_competitor_prices (client, store_id, product_id);

create index if not exists idx_lcp_client_store_product_family_date
on public.last_competitor_prices (client, store_id, product_family_id, date);

create index if not exists idx_lcp_client_date
on public.last_competitor_prices (client, date);

create index if not exists idx_lcp_product_store
on public.last_competitor_prices (product_id, store_id);

create index if not exists idx_lcp_product_family
on public.last_competitor_prices (product_family_id);

create index if not exists idx_lcp_competitor_store
on public.last_competitor_prices (competitor_store_id);

My question is, is there any way to improve either the query or the way it was done, to make this processing faster?
It could be any change, even perhaps migrating to spring batch, I would like some guidance if possible.
Thanks.
Query plan:
Update on products_to_be_priced ptb  (cost=725305.73..1090018.94 rows=1856 width=2210)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=725305.73..1090018.94 rows=1856 width=2210)
        ->  Subquery Scan on fcp  (cost=725305.18..741399.94 rows=53206 width=420)
              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=725305.18..740867.88 rows=53206 width=198)
                    Group Key: agg_competitor_prices.store_id, agg_competitor_prices.product_id, agg_competitor_prices.avg_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.min_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_date_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.source
                    ->  Sort  (cost=725305.18..726635.32 rows=532058 width=156)
                          Sort Key: agg_competitor_prices.store_id, agg_competitor_prices.product_id, agg_competitor_prices.avg_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.min_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_date_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.source
                          ->  Subquery Scan on agg_competitor_prices  (cost=556462.43..591046.20 rows=532058 width=156)
                                ->  WindowAgg  (cost=556462.43..585725.62 rows=532058 width=206)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=556462.43..557792.58 rows=532058 width=134)
                                            Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id
                                            ->  WindowAgg  (cost=418484.87..433116.46 rows=532058 width=134)
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=418484.87..419815.01 rows=532058 width=110)
                                                        Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_family_id, lcp.competitor_store_id
                                                        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=290640.36..306051.90 rows=532058 width=110)
                                                              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=290640.36..295410.74 rows=532058 width=106)
                                                                    Merge Cond: (((lcp.store_id)::text = (ags.store_id)::text) AND ((lcp.product_id)::text = (ags.product_id)::text))
                                                                    ->  Sort  (cost=138719.24..140049.38 rows=532058 width=74)
                                                                          Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on last_competitor_prices lcp  (cost=0.00..64474.77 rows=532058 width=74)
                                                                                Filter: ((date >= '2024-06-09'::date) AND (date <= '2024-06-16'::date) AND ((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text))
                                                                    ->  Sort  (cost=151921.12..152159.77 rows=95462 width=44)
                                                                          Sort Key: ags.store_id, ags.product_id
                                                                          ->  Subquery Scan on ags  (cost=129626.24..141085.15 rows=95462 width=44)
                                                                                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=129626.24..140130.53 rows=95462 width=44)
                                                                                      Group Key: lcp_1.product_id, lcp_1.store_id
                                                                                      ->  Sort  (cost=129626.24..130956.38 rows=532058 width=33)
                                                                                            Sort Key: lcp_1.product_id, lcp_1.store_id
                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on last_competitor_prices lcp_1  (cost=0.00..64474.77 rows=532058 width=33)
                                                                                                  Filter: ((source IS NOT NULL) AND (date >= '2024-06-09'::date) AND (date <= '2024-06-16'::date) AND ((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text))
        ->  Index Scan using products_to_be_priced_client_store_id_product_id_idx on products_to_be_priced ptb  (cost=0.56..6.54 rows=1 width=1368)
              Index Cond: (((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text) AND ((store_id)::text = (fcp.store_id)::text) AND ((product_id)::text = (fcp.product_id)::text))
JIT:
  Functions: 61
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true

Query plan with wrong dates:
Update on products_to_be_priced ptb  (cost=17.68..25.79 rows=1 width=2209)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17.68..25.79 rows=1 width=2209)
        ->  Subquery Scan on fcp  (cost=17.13..17.19 rows=1 width=420)
              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=17.13..17.18 rows=1 width=198)
"                    Group Key: agg_competitor_prices.store_id, agg_competitor_prices.product_id, agg_competitor_prices.avg_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.min_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_date_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.source"
                    ->  Sort  (cost=17.13..17.13 rows=1 width=156)
"                          Sort Key: agg_competitor_prices.store_id, agg_competitor_prices.product_id, agg_competitor_prices.avg_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.min_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.max_date_competitor_price_product, agg_competitor_prices.source"
                          ->  Subquery Scan on agg_competitor_prices  (cost=17.05..17.12 rows=1 width=156)
                                ->  WindowAgg  (cost=17.05..17.11 rows=1 width=206)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=17.05..17.06 rows=1 width=134)
"                                            Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id"
                                            ->  WindowAgg  (cost=17.01..17.04 rows=1 width=134)
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=17.01..17.02 rows=1 width=110)
"                                                        Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_family_id, lcp.competitor_store_id"
                                                        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=16.98..17.00 rows=1 width=110)
                                                              ->  Sort  (cost=16.98..16.98 rows=1 width=106)
"                                                                    Sort Key: lcp.store_id, lcp.product_id"
                                                                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=8.89..16.97 rows=1 width=106)
                                                                          Join Filter: (((lcp.product_id)::text = (lcp_1.product_id)::text) AND ((lcp.store_id)::text = (lcp_1.store_id)::text))
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using idx_lcp_client_date_source on last_competitor_prices lcp  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=74)
                                                                                Index Cond: (((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text) AND (date >= '0202-06-10'::date) AND (date <= '0202-06-16'::date))
                                                                          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=8.46..8.49 rows=1 width=44)
"                                                                                Group Key: lcp_1.product_id, lcp_1.store_id"
                                                                                ->  Sort  (cost=8.46..8.47 rows=1 width=33)
"                                                                                      Sort Key: lcp_1.product_id, lcp_1.store_id"
                                                                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_lcp_client_date_source on last_competitor_prices lcp_1  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=33)
                                                                                            Index Cond: (((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text) AND (date >= '0202-06-10'::date) AND (date <= '0202-06-16'::date) AND (source IS NOT NULL))
        ->  Index Scan using products_to_be_priced_client_store_id_product_id_idx on products_to_be_priced ptb  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=1367)
              Index Cond: (((client)::text = 'HIPER_FARMA'::text) AND ((store_id)::text = (fcp.store_id)::text) AND ((product_id)::text = (fcp.product_id)::text))


Could you add query plan?

Do you have indexes on products_to_be_priced table? Good if (client, store_id, product_id).

@BasilPeace yes added

@ValNik
Yes, I have this index, even in the execution plan it shows

Do you have index transformed_source (product_id,  store_id_? Such an index is not used (in query plan).

None of the indexes on last_competitor_prices are used. That's the problem

I'd try different set and orders of fields: (client, date, source, product_id, store_id) and (date, client, source, product_id, store_id).
Or, if source's cardinality ratio is high, then index the expression source IS NOT NULL instead
Statistics could be old or missing, should be updated then


@BasilPeace, I didn't understand the second point, do you want me to refer to the query plan? I used explain in the entire query

@victorhugo, I mean, you could update statistics (or ask your DBA to do it) and try producing the plan again. If the statistics were not actual before, you could get a different plan, and different performance

Another culprit is DISTINCT in string_agg,  in agg_source. I'm not sure on PostgreSQL, but this construction is notorious for poor performance in some DBMS. You could do DISTINCT in transformed_source and remove DISTINCT from string_agg

@BasilPeace, Even putting the indices in the explain it still doesn't get any of the last_competitor_prices, strangely when I put in a wrong date 202-06-10 for example it uses the indices in the explain, I don't understand
about distinct, do you suggest that I put it in the case as a whole?
I would be able to show it in the query just in the snippet

@BasilPeace, i update my post with query plan wrong dates

Is idx_lcp_client_date_source the new index that you created after my recommendation? If so, I'd try running the query again. The problem could be solved already

@BasilPeace, no is another index, if I pass dates for example: startingDate 2024-06-10 query plan not show indexes scan, but if I pass 202-06-10 indexes show in explain, I don’t undestand

@BasilPeace, your indexes are also doing the same thing, for some data that I test it uses the index in the explanation, but for others it doesn't use it, that's what I don't understand

@victorhugo, without updated query plans and the list of indexes, I have no more ideas

@BasilPeace, ok, thanks for the help, I'll look for more ideas

I have had similar issues in the past. So, I moved the complex SQL query to DBMS level, I simply created a function in the database and called the function from Spring boot @Repository using native query. such.
SELECT column_names FROM function_name(:parameter1, :parameter2, :parameter)

example of PostgreSQL function that return table -> here
you can also use the Materialized view inside the function. link

And how exactly this could improve the performance?

I have the same doubt as @BasilPeace
